# how to trigger function on opening sidemenu in ionic2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2

I need trigger a function when `SideMenu` is open.I searched for this and got this link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/possible-to-trigger-expression-on-opening-sidemenu/4381  for ionic-1 but how can I achieve this in ionic 2 ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject `MenuController` in your page, and then you can access the `isOpen()` method.

```
    import{Page, MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';

    @Page({...})
    export class MyPage {

     constructor(private menu: MenuController) {
     if menu.isOpen() {
        // do something

 }
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.I have added the above code in app.js. it will check the if condition when app loads for the first time and after that it is not  checking `if( menu.isOpen())`.